# only one rule fired can't able to figure out why not all rule executed which declared in drl file

Tags: java, drools

I am new to drool. I have using drool 7. Here is my rule which I have written in drl file.

```
rule "initListFact" dialect "java" when     not List() then     insert( new ArrayList() ); end
```

`rule "TermAndConditionRequest_0_NOTNULL" when obj : TermAndConditionRequest(candidateId == null); result:ConstraintValidationResult();`

In java I have created kieSession object then insert class object and fired rules:-

```
kieSession.insert(classObject);
    kieSession.insert(constraintValidationResult);
    List error = new ArrayList<String>();
    kieSession.setGlobal("errorList", error);
    kieSession.addEventListener(new DroolEventListener());
    int i = kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

I want to execute all rule which I have declared in .drl file but only "initListFact" rule only going to executed. Please help me out on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution why its not working with spring-boot and no rule will be fired because of Drools does not work with spring-boot-devtools.

If you add in pom.xml the following, no rules will be fired in Drools.

```
<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId></dependency>
```

if you comment out this, then rules will be fired correctly in Drools.

Please follow the link for more info :https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1540

Thanks